# Keycloak share common script between theme types

Tags: keycloak

I would like to create common js script file for my types in keycloak
They are defined like:

keycloak-themes.json

```json
{
  "themes": [
    {
      "name": "theme-test",
      "types": [
        "login",
        "account"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and in both directiories I have

- theme/theme-test/login/theme.properties
- theme/theme-test/account/theme.properties

In both i have `scripts= js/script.js`
which is in both located in resources folder and in both contain the same code.

How can i make common file that I can import in script.js file like

```json
scripts = ../common/resources/js/init.js
```

I have created following directory with that file but this doesnt work. Tried absolute and relative path

I tried as well to add 'common' directory to the config like:

```json
{
  "themes": [
    {
      "name": "theme-test",
      "types": [
        "login",
        "account",
        "common"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```